# split a column in excel into two columns keeping leading zeros

Tags: microsoft-excel

How to split a column in excel, keeping leading zeros?

example:

```
column1                column2  column3
+260 0974587           +260     0974587
+667 0007894     to    +667     0007894
+447 4785540           +447     4785540
+458 0054871           +458     0054871
```

Answer (score 3):

In excel, Choose:
1. Data
2. Text to columns
3. Click the 'delimited' radio button
4. Click 'next'
5. Set your delimiter to 'space'
6. Click 'next'
**7. This is the key part! Change the 'column data format' radio button from 'general' to 'text' of any column where you want to retain leading zeros**
8. Click 'finish'

Comment: Note for anybody else running into this issue: This works BUT on step 7 you can't just select 'text' and click finish, you have to select each column individually in the preview box and update each column to text, then click finish.

Answer (score 1):

1. Select your data
2. Go to Data tab - text to columns
3. you've two options:
   a. either select "delimited", then press next and select space as delimiter
   b. either select "fixed width" then press next and move the delimiter line to the desired location
4. press next
5. select second column and set its data format to "text"
6. press finish

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with formula.

For the first part, use `LEFT` function. For the `[num_chars]` parameter of the `LEFT` function, use `FIND` function to get the index of space character.

For the second part, use `RIGHT` function.

**For Column2**

```
=LEFT(A2, FIND(" ", A2) - 1)
```

**For Column3**

```
=RIGHT(A2, FIND(" ", REVERSETEXT(A2)) - 1)
```

**Example**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the three columns correspond to A, B, C and the rows to 1, 2, 3, 4, 5:

1. Write at cell B2

   ```
   =LEFT(A2,4)
   ```

   and copy from B2 to B5.
2. Write at cell C2

   ```
   =TEXT(RIGHT(A2,7),"0000000")
   ```

   and copy from C2 to C5.

Answer (score 0):

I put the data format to "text" but it still removed leading Zeros

#### SOLUTION:

Using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to bring up the Find and Replace Tab, I added a comma before the leading zeros.

My data looked like `Dec. 07` so for me I replaced `.`  with `. ,` which made it look like `Dec. ,07`

Then I did text to column and it kept the leading zeros, simply use find an replace to remove the comma after by replacing `,` with nothing.